# How to be sure that your PHP script is called only by your authorized app?

Tags: php, android, html, ios, networking

Let's say I have a PHP script on the server called process.php. I want to call the script from an iOS/Android app. I want to make it impossible to call the script without the app, for example to call it from a computer. How could I make this verification process secure and unhackable?

Some things I have thinked at:

1. Using a static key that would act like a password to unlock the script. This is not a very good method because once your key is hacked (maybe reverse engineering, the key being stores in your app) they got total access to your script.
2. Creating a hash function and follow the following steps:

   - make a request to the server and get a string
   - hash the string on the local device
   - send the hashed string back
   - if the string received by the server is the same as the string which the server expects (the request send which was hashed on server) I unlock the script
     This way you can get access only if you have the hash function. Is this secure enough?

What other alternatives I have without user's login credentials?

Comment: Are you using ajax calls to access the php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are that concerned, you could create an API key and use HTTPS and attach it to the url in a POST request. Only acknowledging requests that contain the key.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a password.

Store the passwords encrypted into an SQL Database, and then before the server sends the request back, ensure that the password is included in the request. You can use HTTPS if you want to make sure that the password is never sent in plain text.

Your options 2 works, however if you are worried about security then I would use HTTPS.